# How to show input field when clicking on other in select-react

Tags: next.js, react-select

I'm using react-select in nextJS. I need to create an input field when a user clicks on "other" option and take what the user fills.

```
 <SelectComponent
        name={'types'}
        closeMenuOnSelect
        options={[
          { value: 'big', label: 'big' },
          { value: 'small', label: 'small' },
          { value: 'other', label: 'Other' },
        ]}
 />
```

How can this be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A.You define your variable to `show/hide` your `input`

```
const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(false);
```

B. You create your `input component`, and define `hidden` or `display:none` style according to the variable value

```
<input type="text" name="name" style={{display: showInput ? "block": "none"}} />
```

C. You define the behaviour with `onChange` of your `SelectComponent`, something like this

```
onChange={(selected) => {
  //you debug `selected` variable to see values you need etc.
  console.log(selected)
  //you writes if condition here, it's an example of code below
  if (selected == 'other'){
  //showing input
  setShowInput(true)
  }
  else{
  //need set to false if not "others", because user can change select a lot of times
  setShowInput(false)
  }
}}
```

I don't know what are you using as , but when you save your data from the `<form>`, you need always to check your `select` and save data from input only if `"other"` option was selected.